# JavaScript leave/stop/exit the script

Tags: javascript, function, return

I search a methode that leave / stop / exit the script at a line by click "cancel" in the popup of a confirm() function.

```js
var text = "oops!";
function myFunction() {
  var confirmresult = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (confirmresult == true) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "if";
    text = "yeah!"; // by "OK"
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "else";
    text = "ouch!"; // by "cancel"
    return false; // leave/stop/exit here!
  }
}
myFunction();
alert(text); // not by leave/stop/exit;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an `exit()` or `die()` function in Javascript. The best way to do it would be to wrap the rest of your code in an if statement around `myFunction()`:

```
if(myFunction())
{
    alert(text);
    /* ... */
}
```

If you really want to exit a script immediately, throw an uncaught exception:

```
throw(new Error("Script stopped immediately"));
```

Note: I don't recommend doing this.

Comment: Thanks, but the example code is not the real code (~1000 lines). And yes, i don't search non-valid methods. Maybe, an another one has a idea. *wait*